# No value in hidden empty inputs

Tags: javascript

I want to have an empty input against boots:

```
var spam = $('input[name=test]').fieldValue();
if (spam.length > 0){
alert('You are a bot');
return false;
}
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="" />
```

But it is not working. When I don't put anything in the input it still gives the alert "You are a bot". If I change to 1, spam.lenght > 1, then it is working. 
Any ideas?
Thanks!

It turns out that in the plugin used, fieldvalue() was an array: https://github.com/malsup/form

Comment: What is `.fieldValue()`?  What library are you using?  jQuery?  Prototype.js?  Something else?

Comment: You should use .val() I believe. I have never heard of fieldValue. Also what is the value returned for spam?

Comment: I am using jquery.form

Comment: What is the `typeof spam`? Is it `"string"` or `"object"`? If `.fieldValue()` happens to return a collection of values, it will always have a `length > 0` since there is at least one matching element, even if the 1st value in it is empty. [**Edit**] And, [that may be the case](https://github.com/malsup/form/#fieldvalue): "*Returns the value(s) of the element(s) in the matched set in an array. This method always returns an array.*"

Comment: What is `jquery.form`? Please provide actual, useful information. If that's a publicly available plugin, post a link to its website.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it should be with val(). it is working now. fieldvalue() was from a jquery plugin (jquery.form) that I am using. I don't know it wasn't working. I see that you deleted your answer...

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Ok, now I understand. It was an array. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `jQuery.form` plugin you referred to is http://malsup.com/jquery/form/, then [`.fieldValue()` is returning an `Array`](https://github.com/malsup/form/#fieldvalue):

> Returns the value(s) of the element(s) in the matched set in an array. This method always returns an array. If no valid value can be determined the array will be empty, otherwise it will contain one or more values.

This means you're testing the `Array`'s `length` rather than the `<input>`'s `value`. The latter will be in an index of the collection:

```
var testValues = $('input[name=test]').fieldValue();
var spam = testValues[0];

if (spam.length > 0){
    // ...
}
```

You can also use jQuery's own [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead, as it will only return a single `value`, if you don't need the collection:

```
var spam = $('input[name=test]').val();

if (spam.length > 0){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I was searching for the answer for quite some time